# Is there an iOS alternative to HTC's Zoe?

Tags: iphone, ios, software-recommendation, android

I'm considering a switch back to iPhone and iOS from my Android powered HTC One (M7) phone. HTC created a super cool app called Zoe. I'm wondering if there is an equally good alternative to Zoe on iOS.

If you don't know what Zoe is, it takes your media (photos, videos) and creates really nice, themed video clips. Themes influence things like background music, video transition effects, various graphics effects (old film, zoom, etc.)

See this video for example of a Zoe:

[London pt. 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s8C_yoYUYds)

**Update from 6/16/2016**

At the WWDC 16 Keynote Apple presented a new Photos feature called Memories. This is basically exactly what Zoe does on HTC.

Comment: Have you taken a look at iMovie?

Comment: Briefly, and it looks like a great, albeit simplistic, mobile video editor. Zoe is a *smart, automated video generator* with basic customizable settings. Zoe randomly chooses media to generate videos. It employs smart algorithms that detect sections of videos that contain action scenes, or more calm ones, to match an associated theme's video transition effects and background music. So, iMovie is a brush with which one could learn to paint. Zoe is a magic wand that creates "pictures" with one button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to take a look at [Quik](https://appsto.re/de/ZSbyP.i). This app was called replay, doing exactly what you are looking for. They got acquired by GoPro, and the name changed to Quik.

Comment: Nice. They even support Android. Is there anything else similar to HTC Zoe or Quik?

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately there is no such official application, but you might find similar in App Store.

Comment: Official or not. The question is if there is an alternative.